# members list SQL query whitout showing mutual friends, pending approval friends, blocked friends

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have complex SQL QUERY I need some Help for the following conditions:

I'm looking for an SQL query with the below conditions:

```
SELECT *  FROM Table_1,Table_2 where user_id = ’16’ // 16 = ($_SESSION[ 'SESS_USER_ID' ])
```

- CONDITION 1 ->  DON’T SHOW MYSELF (CURRENT login user_id. => 16 (IT’s ME) ($_SESSION[ 'SESS_USER_ID' ]))
- CONDITION 2 ->  DON’T SHOW user_id 25, 26, 27, 28 in the list because they are already in table_2 for with some conditions for user_id =’16’ and CONDITION 0,1 from friend_status
- CONDITION 3 -> ORDER BY signupdate

Sample of the result I am expecting below:
WHAT I NEED-> I need the results showing all the members for login 'user_id' that are not in Table_2 'friend_status' CONDITION (0,1,2)

In the below table results, you can see that login 'user_id' (16 in this example) cannot see other 'user_id' that are in Table_2 CONDITION (0,1,2) including himself as the login 'user_id' (16)

```
//Perfect SQL results for me.
+—————————+—————————————+
+ user_id +signupdate   + 
+—————————+—————————————+
+   23    + 2020-11-30  +
+—————————+—————————————+
+   24    + 2020-11-30  +
+—————————+—————————————+
+   28    + 2020-11-30  +
+—————————+—————————————+
+   21    + 2020-11-30  +
+—————————+—————————————+
```

WHAT I NEED -> I need the an SQL QUERY to show results showing all the members for login 'user_id'(16) that are not in Table_2 'friend_status' CONDITION (0,1,2)

PROBLEM-> The Results I am getting below don't match the requested 'friend_status' CONDITION (0,1,2) of Table_2.

WHY? Because login 'user_id' should no see all the 'friend_status' CONDITION (0,1,2) in the full members page results that have
NO CONDITION (0,1,2)

WHY? Because These SQl results CONDITION (0,1,2) are displayed elsewhere in 3 differents results pages for each CONDITION (0,1,2) -> Not todays topic.

```
//Wrong SQL results for me.
+—————————+—————————————+
+ user_id +signupdate
+—————————+—————————————+
+   16    + 2020-11-30  + <— SHOULD DO NOT SHOW, CONDITION-> ITS ME “login”  $user_id = ’16’
+—————————+—————————————+
+   23    + 2020-11-30  +
+—————————+—————————————+
+   24    + 2020-11-30  +
+—————————+—————————————+
+   25    + 2020-11-30  +<— SHOULD NOT SHOW -> TABLE_2  CONDITION user_id = ( $_SESSION[ 'SESS_USER_ID' ])=’16’ AND CONDITION2 friend_status= ‘0’(Pending approval Mutual friends)
+—————————+—————————————+
+   26    + 2020-11-30  +<— SHOULD NOT SHOW -> TABLE_2 CONDITION user_id = ( $_SESSION[ 'SESS_USER_ID' ])=’16’ AND CONDITION2 friend_status= ‘0’ (Pending approval Mutual friends)
+—————————+—————————————+
+   27    + 2020-11-30  +<— SHOULD NOT SHOW -> TABLE_2 CONDITION user_id = ( $_SESSION[ 'SESS_USER_ID' ])=’16’ AND CONDITION2 friend_status= ‘1’ (Mutual friends)
+—————————+—————————————+
+   28    + 2020-11-30  +<— SHOULD NOT SHOW -> TABLE_2 CONDITION user_id = ( $_SESSION[ 'SESS_USER_ID' ])=’16’ AND CONDITION2 friend_status= ‘2’ (Blocked)
+—————————+—————————————+
+   21    + 2020-11-30  +
+—————————+—————————————+
```

TABLE_2 (table for friends relationship)
friend_status=‘0’ -> This means 'user_id'  pending friendship acceptance by 'user_id_resquest' -> Do not Show in full members list for login 'user_id'
friend_status=‘1’ -> This 'user_id' and 'user_id_resquest' are already mutual friends. -> Do not Show in full members list for login user_id
friend_status=‘2’ -> This means 'user_id' is blocked by 'user_id_resquest' -> Do not Show in members list for current login user_id

```
+——————————————+—————————+——————————————+—————————————————+
+friendship_id + user_id + user_id_request + friend_status+
+——————————————+—————————+——————————————+—————————————————+
+   1          +   16    +        26    +        0        +//0->Pending
+——————————————+—————————+——————————————+—————————————————+
+   2          +   16    +        25    +        0        +//0->Pending
+——————————————+—————————+——————————————+—————————————————+
+   3          +   16    +        27    +        1        +//1->Mutual
+——————————————+—————————+——————————————+—————————————————+
+   4          +   21    +        27    +        1        +//1->Mutual
+——————————————+—————————+——————————————+—————————————————+
+   5          +   16    +        28    +        2        +//2 ->blocked
+——————————————+—————————+——————————————+—————————————————+
```

TABLE_1 (table of all the users)

```
+—————————+—————————————+
+ user_id + signupdate  +
+—————————+—————————————+
+   16    + 2020-11-30  + 
+—————————+—————————————+
+   23    + 2020-11-30  +
+—————————+—————————————+
+   24    + 2020-11-30  +
+—————————+—————————————+
+   25    + 2020-11-30  +
+—————————+—————————————+
+   26    + 2020-11-30  +
+—————————+—————————————+
+   27    + 2020-11-30  +
+—————————+—————————————+
+   28    + 2020-11-30  +
+—————————+—————————————+
```

Comment: I'm lost.  Your explanation would really benefit by showing the data you are starting with, then explaining the conditions and showing the results you want.

Comment: This is not a good question title.  Please [edit] to better express the crux of your question.

Comment: We need sample data with friend status = 2 to have a [mcve].

Comment: What happens if the status is `2`? You said it means that the user is blocked but didn't mention whether it should be shown in the result or not. The data sample also don't have any cell with `status=2`.

Comment: friend_status = '0' // Pending , friend_status = '1' //Mutual friends, friend_status = '2' // Blocked

Comment: The reason that I edited your title is because future researchers that will want to find this page are not likely to be using specific keywords like "mutual fiends pending approval friends".  I was trying to make your question more searchable based on my many years of experience curating content on Stack Overflow.  When I need to use the advice on this page to close a new duplicate, I am not likely to find this page by searching the intuitive keywords relating to the necessary techniques.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure which of the following will perform better with your real project data, so I recommend that you benchmark both to see if one performs noticeably better than the other.

Codes: ([Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7ycagCRaujukKSzrm4z8RU/1))

1. Subquery on every row of Table_1 needing 2 placeholders in a prepared statement <sup>(might not perform well)</sup>

   ```
   SELECT user_id, signupdate
   FROM Table_1 AS t1
   WHERE user_id != 16
     AND NOT EXISTS(
               SELECT 1
               FROM Table_2
               WHERE user_id_request = t1.user_id
                 AND user_id = 16
             );
   ```
2. Left join needing only 1 place holder in a prepared statement:

   ```
   SELECT t1.user_id, t1.signupdate
   FROM Table_1 AS t1
   LEFT JOIN Table_2 AS t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id_request
   WHERE 16 NOT IN (t1.user_id, COALESCE(t2.user_id,0))
     AND t2.friendship_id IS NULL;
   ```

Both output:

```
| user_id | signupdate |
| ------- | ---------- |
| 23      | 2020-11-30 |
| 24      | 2020-11-30 |
| 21      | 2020-11-30 |
```

Comment: @Gordon Do you have a moment to review my suggestions?  I'd like to know that I am not giving any bad advice.  If there is anything foolish/bad in these techniques, please set me straight.  For instance, should I not use `IN` to shorten the syntax because it will have an unwanted cost on performance?

Comment: Your approach for the N°2 answer is excellent, because for what I understand => whatever 'friendstatus' (0,1,2) in table_2 as long as my user_id =’16' exist in table_2,  the QUERY is working as I want. I don't see  myself in member list (user_id =’16’ )(working condition)  and I don't see any of the 'user_id_request' associated to my user_id ='16' in the member list Query. This works perfectly, the memberlist is showing only members that I have no relationship in table_2. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, get rid of the comma-join and replace it with a `JOIN`; a `LEFT JOIN` in particular. Besides, you're basically doing a `CROSS JOIN` by not adding a `WHERE` on matching columns between the two tables. I'm not sure if that's what you intended to do though.

Try with this query:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t2.user_id,t1.user_id) AS user_id,
      t1.signupdate,
      CASE 
           WHEN t2.user_id='16'/*($_SESSION[ 'SESS_USER_ID' ])*/ 
              AND friend_status IN (0,1) THEN 0
           WHEN t1.user_id='16'/*($_SESSION[ 'SESS_USER_ID' ])*/ THEN 0
           ELSE 1 END AS Chk
FROM Table_1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN Table_2 AS t2 
ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id_request 
HAVING Chk=1;
```

In the query, I've used `LEFT JOIN` on table_1's `user_id` column matching with table_2's `user_id_request` column. This is because if I match them between `user_id` in both table, `table_2` will only show where `user_id=16` and the rest as `NULL`, therefore those data that you want to filter from `table_2` will not appear. In the `SELECT ..`  section of the query, I've used two operations, `COALESCE` and a `CASE` expression. The `CASE` expression is used to filter out the current `user_id` and give it `0`(zero) if it matches the condition and gives it `1` for other data that didn't match. This I assigned alias `Chk` and uses it at the end of the query on `HAVING`. For the `COALESE` part, I'm returning any `user_id` from `table_2` first, then return `user_id` from `table_1` if the `table_2` is `NULL`.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=04877318d86a6d5bf9f7b6f5c0101a18)

**Edit:** Without using `HAVING`, check the `CASE` expression at `WHERE` like:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t2.user_id,t1.user_id) AS user_id,
      t1.signupdate
FROM Table_1 AS t1 LEFT JOIN Table_2 AS t2 
ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id_request
WHERE CASE 
           WHEN t2.user_id='16'/*($_SESSION[ 'SESS_USER_ID' ])*/ 
                   AND friend_status IN (0,1) THEN 0
           WHEN t1.user_id='16'/*($_SESSION[ 'SESS_USER_ID' ])*/ THEN 0
           ELSE 1 END=1;
```

Comment: I'm not sure that I support using HAVING.  Can't this be done with ON and WHERE logic?

Comment: Yes it can @mickmackusa. Just shift the `CASE` expression into `WHERE`. Please check my edit.

Comment: So are you saying the the logic holds up if you just use `WHERE 16 NOT IN (t1.user_id, t2.user_id)`?  (I have not tested because I am at work)  This way, `$_SESSION[ 'SESS_USER_ID' ]` can be bound to the prepared statement just once.

Comment: @mickmackusa , with my current query it only return 1 row from table_2

Comment: Here's what I found, the data the OP required to return is from both tables, something that could be done using `UNION` but with a much longer query in my opinion. The expected result is including `user_id=21` and that data only appears in `table_2` and the link is coming from `user_id=27` that wasn't linked with `user_id=16`.

Comment: ...I don't know, I don't have time to study this one.  I just feel that these sql queries are not quite as elegant as they can be.

Comment: I feel the same @mickmackusa. I'm also worried if there's some data that will break the query. I probably should just try and see if the `UNION` query I had in mind is more convincing.

Comment: Please take note of the conditions in Condition 2: `user_id =’16’ and CONDITION 0,1 from friend_status`

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot about that. Although I am curious as to what happens if the status is `2`?

Comment: @FaNo_FN friend_status = '2' // means Blocked

Answer (score 1):

It appears you basically need a left-join from the user table to the who is friended or pending.  You are not clear if the person is marked as an ID = 2.  If they are marked as blocked, would you not want their name to show up as a possible friend/friend request anyhow?  So in short, you want anybody who is not your (current logged-in user) and has not already been requested as friend = 0, confirmed as friend = 1, OR already requested but BLOCKED user = 2.  Why show someones name you wanted blocked.

```
select
      T1.*
   from
      Table1 T1
   where
          NOT T1.User_ID = ($_SESSION[ 'SESS_USER_ID' ])
      AND T1.User_ID NOT IN ( select T2.user_id_request
                                 from Table2 T2
                                 where T2.User_ID = ($_SESSION[ 'SESS_USER_ID' ])) 
   order by 
      T1.SignupDate
```

Just make sure you are properly parameterizing your queries and not using direct variables to build your query strings. You will be wide-open to sql-injection.

Comment: Condition 2: `user_id =’16’ and CONDITION 0,1 from friend_status` -- I think we need a better [mcve].  Why not use `T1.User_ID != ($_SESSION[ 'SESS_USER_ID' ])` instead of `WHERE NOT`?  What about `NOT EXISTS()`?

Comment: @mickmackusa, the where NOT user = 16 (via session) is same as user_id != 16.  As for the friend condition, people put what they probably do not need.  did you read the leading context / explanation of my answer?  We are trying to get what they need, not necessarily just what was described.  Reading between the lines of the probable desired want.